# Unable to install packages in rstudio

Tags: r, tidyverse

> install.packages("tidyverse")
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but are not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
>   https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
>   also installing the dependencies ‘desc’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘pkgload’, ‘praise’, ‘colorspace’, ‘sys’, ‘ps’, ‘highr’, ‘markdown’, ‘plyr’, ‘testthat’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘askpass’, ‘rematch’, ‘prettyunits’, ‘processx’, ‘knitr’, ‘yaml’, ‘htmltools’, ‘evaluate’, ‘base64enc’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘backports’, ‘generics’, ‘reshape2’, ‘assertthat’, ‘glue’, ‘fansi’, ‘DBI’, ‘R6’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘BH’, ‘plogr’, ‘digest’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘scales’, ‘withr’, ‘vctrs’, ‘curl’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘utf8’, ‘clipr’, ‘cellranger’, ‘progress’, ‘callr’, ‘fs’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘whisker’, ‘selectr’, ‘stringi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘broom’, ‘cli’, ‘crayon’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘forcats’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lubridate’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘purrr’, ‘readr’, ‘readxl’, ‘reprex’, ‘rlang’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘rvest’, ‘stringr’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘xml2’

Comment: I have downloaded R and R studio but it's still got a problem in installing packages in r studio.

Comment: Please add R and R studio versions and which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Rtools separately from R and RStudio.
Have a look at https://ohdsi.github.io/Hades/rSetup.html.